# Response Error : [AxiosError: Network Error] at XMLHttpRequest.handleError on AVD and Iphone

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I am new to react-native and facing this Axios network error on the register function in my firstApp

Here is my endpoint for registration

```
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
 const { name, email, password, image } = req.body;
  // create a new User object
 const newUser = new User({ name, email, password, image });
 // save the user to the database
 newUser
.save()
.then(() => {
  res.status(200).json({ message: "User registered successfully" });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error registering user", err);
  res.status(500).json({ message: "Error registering the user!" });
});
```

});

And here is the handleRegister function in RegisterScreens

```
// send a POST  request to the backend API to register the user
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8000/register", user)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    Alert.alert(
      "Registration successful",
      "You have been registered Successfully"
    );
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setImage("");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Registration Error",
      "An error occurred while registering"
    );
    console.log("registration failed", error);
  });
```

I have tried adding a user on the web and it works, but it is not the same on AVD or my iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Get your IpV4 address by typing **ipconfig** in your terminal

Step 2: Host your API at your IpV4 address instead of localhost (for eg :- 192.168.0.106:8000)

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 8000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello Network!")
});

app.listen(port, '192.168.77.112', ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening port on ${port}`)
});
```

Step 3: Run your API first

Step 4: Fetch the data from the new address (for eg :- 192.168.0.106:8000)